# Load local file (in solution explorer)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, path

I have json file in folder D:\Projects\TravelVloggers\ProjectName.Web\Helpers\Folder_1\myFile.

How can I load this file? Later I want to deserialize it.

I do not want to put path to local file in my disk.

Comment: Where do you want to deserialize it? Is your application ASP.NET MVC, or ASP.NET Web forms or any other?

Comment: My question is about load file. How can I load file to some object. I can handle with deserialization

Comment: You can add this file to your solution and set it's build property to 'Copy If Newer'.

There are types of adding such kind of files. In case of ASP.NET MVC applications Content folder is suitable place, etc.

Please be more specific.

Comment: Okay, I know that. But now how can I load this file to my object. I mean something like: var jsonFile = path to my file.

Comment: What do you mean by "load"? Do you want to hold the string contents of a JSON file in a string variable in your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are working in ASP.NET MVC, add your file to Content folder and read with JSON.NET library. Firstly read the file then deserialize, that's it.

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/Content/file.json")))
{
      yourObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObjectType>(sr.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Pay attention to add mimetype in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json; charset=UTF-8" />

    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: If you think a question is answered in another question, flag to close as duplicate. If you need multiple answers to support your answer, then put the relevant parts in your answer. Link-only answers aren't answers. :) If the question is unclear, don't guess in an answer but use comments to ask for clarification instead.

Comment: @CodeCaster does it look now OK?

Comment: I'm not sure what the mime type has to do with it and I'm not sure OP wants to deserialize, but sure, now it looks like a valid answer. :) Thanks.